# Launching jupyter lab opens an empty page

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I have been using Anaconda for sometime. Suddenly Jupyter doesn't launch.

Steps :

1. install the anaconda;
2. open Anaconda Prompt;
3. type in Anaconda Prompt 'jupyter notebook'.
4. redirect to `http://localhost:8888/tree`

I get a white page.

Comment: which browser, OS, python version?

Comment: Are you actually starting "jupyterlab". The correct command should be `jupyter lab`. See the [documentation](https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/getting_started/starting.html)

Comment: i get the same result (white page)

Comment: In JupyterLab, this happens sometimes because of corrupted browser storage. Please try to clear your browser's cache, cookies and offline content. Or open the page in a "Private Window"

Comment: @DejanMarić  python version 3.7 && system: win10 && browser :Spark

Comment: can you try with chrome or internet explorer?

Comment: @gdlmx thanks u bro it's work in private window